# Iterating over the properties defined by an Interface in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Pre Angular 12 this used to work:

```
export interface Content {
    categories: string[]
    concepts: Topic[]
    formulas: Topic[]
    guides: Topic[]
}

//this.content is of type Content
['formulas', 'concepts'].forEach(c => {
      this.content[c].forEach(topic => {
//....
      });
    })
```

However now it produces the error (For the line `this.content[c]`):

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Content'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Content'.ts(7053)

How do I tell Typescript that `this.content[c]` is an array of `Topic` instances?

Comment: Do you mean _without casting_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use it like this:

```
['formulas', 'concepts'].forEach(c => {
    this.content[c as keyof Content].forEach(topic => {
        //....
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the design to this:

```
export interface ContentContainer {
    categories: string[]
    keyedTopics:Content
}

export interface Content {
    [key: string]: Topic[]
}
```

This way each `string` key always maps to a `Topic` array.